# Identify Transistors

Tags: transistors

I have some old parts I am trying to identify but all the books I have are old and the numbers don't show up.

I have an item marked 43A175-973P1 in a TO18 case. Also, 6932T6948 in a TO18, and a (3789-3 7552) in a TO3 case.

Any help in identifying these items would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I expecvt that these are "house numbers" - an equipment manufacturer's internal stock numbers, rather than a common, readily avaialble, part number.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a little guesswork and you can get lucky.

Distant memory and a search for 2n3789 shows a [60V 10A PNP transistor in a TO-3 package](http://uk.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Central-Semiconductor/2N3789/?qs=RS415aRcUaEQAF8y3iPydA==). A little diode testing with a multimeter will tell if your samples are PNP or not, making this at least plausible. The remaining digits would suggest a manufacture date in late December 1975.

The luck stops there though, at least for me : a 2N6932 is not (from the specs I can find) anything you would see in a TO-18 and 43A175 rings no bells at all.

As Peter Bennett says, it could be a code from some large manufacturer - Hewlett-Packard and Burroughs at least had their own 8-digit numbers for any IC or transistor they used, and to win a big enough order, any semiconductor maker would print these codes on parts for them; usually omitting the original part number to make reverse engineering a little harder.